# Rails4 + Paperclip: Url and Path not matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, get, paperclip

I use paperclip to upload a users avatar. The image is stored correctly in the /public directory. However I cant figure out how I can get the image displayed. I played with the :url and :path settings for about an hour and cant match them in a way the image will be displayed in the browser. 
There is always a *'images/localhost'* in the GET-requests path that I can not get rid of.
Here is my code:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "missing.png",
   :url => ':class/:id/:style.:extension',
   :path => ':url'
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**The path in the html-tag looked up by the request looks like this:**

```
 <img alt="Original" src="/images/localhost/users/1/original.png?1405249849" />
```

The correct request which returns the image would be
    `http://localhost:3000/users/1/original.png?1405248482.`

How can I get the request match the correct file-system-path. Or: what is wrong with my settings?

I didnt change the application.rb or the development.rb

Best regards,
Kev

Answer (score 0):

you should take url or path helpers of `paperclip` wherever possible. So to show the image use:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

Then:
the image url isn't a file system path. Depending on the storage you use in paperclip, images can reside in different places, see [understanding storage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) of the paperclip gem.

If you use file storage, the files are store somewhere like

```
public/system/users/avatar/000/000/013/small/my_pic.png
```

Comment: Sorry, I use <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> to display the image. I just wanted to show the html it is translated to. That is the exact problem. The path it gives me does not match the path of the image.

Comment: I changed the :path to the one suggested in the paperclip documentation. The file is located in my rails-application under /public/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/me.png and i can request it successfully using http://localhost:3000/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/me.png.

Still, the <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> returns `http://localhost:3000/images/localhost/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/me.png?1405256832` which is wrong and cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

**Timestamp**

What you're seeing is [Paperclip's timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710829/paperclip-image-url) - the last time the file / object was updated.

Although I can't find any official reference to this number, it basically allows you to determine which files you're dealing with. According to the question referenced above, it's apparently there for if you want to ensure your visitors see the latest version of the file (IE never gets stored in the `cache`)

I'm not sure why there is a disparity between your stored image & your path. However, I would say the path is correct; you just need to be able to

--

Bottom line - if your image shows on the page, I don't think there's any systemic issue with your path; if it doesn't show on the page, can you provide logs / reference to the error?

Comment: Thank you, the difference in the timestamp is not the problem. I see that I should have pointed that out more clearly. The problem is in the beginning of the path. Sorry for that!
Logs: 
Started GET "/images/localhost/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/me.png?1405258473" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 17:10:22 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/localhost/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/me.png"):

The correct path of the image is nearly the same, just without the leading "/images/localhost/". I dont understand where this addon comes from?

Answer (score 0):

This post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26222093/1949363, which pointed to http://www.bwigg.com/2009/10/paperclip-customizing-paths-and-urls/ was the answer for me. I was having issues only in my test environment but I believe the fix should work in other environments as well.

Try the following settings:

```
:path => "public/system/:class/:id/:filename",
:url => "/system/:class/:id/:basename.:extension"
```