# Paperclip :url does not create Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

What is the point of using the :url option with paperclip? The :path option does in fact change the location where the file is saved, but the :url option doesn't seem to do a thing. It only works when it points to a publicly accessible file location. At that point, the url is already accessible to anyone. If I change the url so that it doesn't match the path, it does not work. As far as I can tell, it does not create any routes either way. Is there something I am missing here. What is the point of this option? It seems overly confusing to let someone specify a :url without actually creating a route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.bwigg.com/2009/10/paperclip-customizing-paths-and-urls/) useful in understanding the difference between `:path` and `:url`.

- `:path` sets the directory in your application where the file is stored.
- `:url` sets the url that users can use to access the image.

You are right, paperclip does not create a route for you. However, the `:url` option does give you the ability to select which (existing) route your users can use to download a specific image.

`:path` and `:url` usually go hand in hand. If you stick to the paperclip `:default_url` the path is already configured for you. Just hit the url and everything will work fine.

**Changing the file location**

In this example I am rendering a users avatar:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

Now, lets say that you wanted to change the location that images are stored, you can add the following code to your model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :path => "public/system/:class/:id/:filename"
```

However, the image will not render successfully. This is because the new path, where your images are stored, does not match the `:default_url`. Therefore, you will also need to specify a new url:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :path => "public/system/:class/:id/:filename"
    :url => "/system/:class/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Now the image url matches the location that the file is stored on your server and the image renders successfully.

**Path vs URL**

To summarize, `:url` tells paperclip where abouts on the server to look for an image. `:path` tells paperclip where to upload an image, when creating or updating a record.

Both `:path` and `:url` should point to the same location, in order to render an image successfully.

Comment: If I can only point the `:url` to a route that already exists, what is the point? How does using this option help? If there is already a route, isn't my job done?

Comment: @wdhilliard I've updated my answer with a better explanation. Essentially `:url` tells paperclip where to access your images. `:path` tells paperclip where to upload images. They need to match up to render an image successfully

Comment: I think my confusion was due to the fact that I was not using Paperclip to generate the url for me. Thanks for your detailed answer.