# Rails4 | Paperclip: image is uploaded but it doesn't displays well (strange url is returned)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload images in rails, the images are saved well, but then, `<%= @user.avatar.url %>` returns this:

```
/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/1000203288934_DOCF635653TS102451125.gif%3F1416704056
/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/10407722_1175881652452049_8262371134443675175_n.jpg%3F1416705182
```

instead of just:

```
/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/1000203288934_DOCF635653TS102451125.gif
/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original/10407722_1175881652452049_8262371134443675175_n.jpg
```

It happens for every image I upload. Where the hell that %3F-whatever at the end of the url comes from? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is what Paperclip uses for cache-busting. If you want to remove it, just call `@user.avatar.url(:original, timestamp: false)`

You can also disable this globally by putting the following in the `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` file.

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711129/85125) answer explains why you may want cache-busting in place though.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It looks to be related to [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1706). Disable it for the time-being while a fix is being worked out.