# How to tell browser to accept timestamped paperclip css files stored in S3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I need to save customized `CSS` files into AWS S3 using paperclip, and load them back in html file using paperclip attachment url. So, the `link` tag will looks something like:

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/....../theme.css20190126-23995-3w63v8.css?1548515496">
```

Loading the file in Firefox will show the following error in console:

> The stylesheet
>   https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/....../theme.css20190126-23995-3w63v8.css?1548515496
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”.

I tried using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710829/paperclip-image-url) and added `.url(:default, timestamp: false)` to attachment url. However this give a wrong file url for browser and CSS file is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 returns default content-type "text/plain", so you should set Metadata on AWS S3.

1. Log in your AWS console.
2. Go to your file (xxx/xxx/theme.css20190126-23995-3w63v8.css) on AWS S3 console.
3. Open Properties tab of your file.
4. Add content-type click "+ Add Metadata" on Metadata section.

Of course, you can modify Metadata from programs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-upload-bucket-item-with-metadata.html